# Errors while building APK which is TransformException

Tags: android

I try to build APK in Android Studio, but it shows error message is

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I can build apk successfully in other app , so i don't know why the message.

Has anyone can teach me how to solve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: Dear all : This type of question already asked on here . Please add comment instead of Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `multiDex` in gradle:

```
    android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

To know more about the cause of this issue, read this [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: thanks @OBX , it saves me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines in the build.gradle:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and in your manifest,

```
<application
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>
```

Comment: thanks @Mayura Devani , i got the solution.